# Problems with the usage of new api's of the distribute cache

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I tried to run the hadoop program using the new api's of the distributed cache. I am stuck with the below error messages.

```
14/11/04 10:54:36 WARN fs.FileUtil: Command 'ln -s /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1415078671812/normal_small /home/yogi/Desktop/normal_small' failed 1 with: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/yogi/Desktop/normal_small’: Permission denied

14/11/04 10:54:36 WARN mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Failed to create symlink: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1415078671812/normal_small <- /home/yogi/Desktop/normal_small

java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/master:54310/usr/local/hadoop/input/normal_small (No such file or directory)
```

I have never mentioned anything about /home/yogi/Desktop/normal_small in my code. Can't understand from where it is trying to access that file.

Also, how should I give the input file path in the driver class to solve the file not found exception?

Below are my mapper and driver class snippets:

**Mapper:**

```
BufferedReader in = null;
  FileReader fr = null;
  private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


  @Override
  protected void setup(Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
      URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();


      try {
          fr = new FileReader(cacheFiles[0].toString());
          in = new BufferedReader(fr);
          String str;
          while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
              list.add(str);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          in.close();
          fr.close();
      }

  }


public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
    oos.writeObject(list); // write MenuArray to ObjectOutputStream


    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output"));


       String line=br.readLine();
        .........
}
```

**Driver:**

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
job.setJobName("wordcount");
job.setJarByClass(driver.class);        
job.addCacheFile(new Path("hdfs://master:54310/usr/local/hadoop/input/normal_small").toUri());
```

Comment: I think, the `hdfs://master:54310` part is not needed at all. It doesn't explain the phantom path look up however.

Comment: @blackSmith: The error still conitnues. It is showing file not found exception. I am using multinode hadoop cluster btw

Comment: your path `/usr/local/hadoop/input/normal_small` seems to point to a local file. The file should be in HDFS to be cached across the nodes.

Comment: @blackSmith:  the above path is in HDFS only

Comment: Perhaps the missing symlink part is causing problem(warn msgs pointing to the same). Just change the fileName as `normal_small#normalLink`.

Comment: @blackSmith: thanks. atleast the symlink warning is gone now

Comment: I get the same error while running the stock example for WordCount

Answer (score 0):

When you add files to distributed cache, It will create a temporary directory. So change the ownership of that directory to the current user.